# rails performance test warmup time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I am using a rails performance test run as `rake test:benchmark`. The result gives me the warmup time. 
I can't find the meaning of the 211 ms warm up time. Some of the test take longer warmup
time. I know what **wall_time**, **user_time** and etc.

```
.ApiTest#test_license_pool (211 ms warmup)
           wall_time: 167 ms
           user_time: 47 ms
              memory: 6.2 MB
             gc_runs: 0
             gc_time: 0 ms
```

Comment: I think warmup time is the time that it takes to set up the test. could you go into more details about what specifically you're asking?

Comment: Some of test show large warmup time. Just want to make sure large warmup time doesn't mean performance is bad.  And do I need to do anyting about any large warm up time.